# Does Book of Revelations always spawn a Harbinger?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

According to the [Binding of Isaac Rebirth wiki](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Book_Of_Revelations):

> If The Book of Revelations is used at least once in a map, a Harbinger will replace the normal level boss.

I've found **Book of Revelations** in a *Library Room* in *Basement 1* after defeating *Pin* boss. So I moved to *Basement 2* in order to activate the book and make my next boss **Famine**. In theory.

The fact is that I found **Larry** as Basement 2 boss. How is this possible? I mean, the book should replace my next boss with a Harbinger. Why not this time?

*Meat Boy* and *Bandage Girl* achievements are driving me nuts...

Comment: Are you *sure* it was the Book of Revelations? A couple of books have a similar appearance.

Comment: Yes, I'm not dumb... It gave me a Soul Heart each activation.

Comment: A soul heart or a black heart?

Comment: Soul, I know the difference between Book of Revelations and Satanic Bible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard somewhere that the Horsemen can only spawn on the first floors. Basement/Cellar I, Caves/Catacombs I, Depths/Necropolis I, etc. But I can't find reliable information online to support this.

Also, this might also be why - According to [platinumgod.co.uk](http://platinumgod.co.uk/),

> Using this item gives you a higher chance of finding a horsemen boss at the end of the floor.

This might mean that the Book of Revelations only gives you a *higher chance* (although a very high one at that) of spawning a Horseman for the boss.

And if you're looking to get the Meat Boy/Bandage Girl achievements, save yourself the pain of Conquest ruining your day and go for the Monster Manual + infinite item charge approach.

Comment: I've heard that, too. But that's not true, because I've found Pestilence in Catacombs II recently using *Book of Revelations*. Anyway you may be right, I've always thought that would be a 100% chance. [Rebirth wikia](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Book_Of_Revelations) doesn't give exact information.

Comment: Oh, and I've already got those achievements using Monster Manual abuse, that was the easiest way indeed.